# Is there a way to introduce a block of code into a method in a newly generated class using NetBeans IDE?

Tags: java, refactoring, netbeans-8

Using NetBeans IDE 8.2, is there a way to introduce a block of code into a method and put this method in a newly created class.

Say I have

```
public class A{
    public void sumMethod(){
        stmt1;
        stmt2;
        stmt3;
        stmt4;
    }
}
```

Then I want to move stmt3,and stmt4 into a new created class, say class B with a method name newMethod().

Comment: You are looking for a way to "extract to method"?

Comment: Introducing a method in a newly generated class.What I can find in Netbeans is to introduce a method in the same class.

Answer (score 1):

You must combine the following steps:

1. Create the new class
2. Extract the method
3. Move the method to the new class

Comment: And this is what I don't want. I need the 3 steps in 1.

Comment: I think intelliJ has this feature but I am not sure.